# Adding gesture event to custom element Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

As per the polymer documentation there are 2 methods to add Gesture events:
1. Annotated event listener

Extend the element using

```html
    class TestEvent extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element) {
```

and add annotation for the element

```html
<div id="dragme" on-track="handleTrack">Drag me!</div>
```

when i try this , though events get triggered native handling of browser events stop. Though I call Polymer.Gestures.setTouchAction(this,"auto"); inside ready it fails.
Please suggest how should I go about adding gesture events in annotation form and still allowing native browser handling.

Comment: Please post your code.